# Python3 Unix command_line_interface task organizer application using argparse

Tags: python-3.x, console

**Greetings.**

Lately I've tried to use a branch of [**text_formatting rules**](https://github.com/NyvoStudio/StyleGuide) to enhance my productivity while working with different integration tools such as Git, but this formatting convention went so
deep into my life that I thought that writing my To-Do list while adhering to it would be
a good idea.

Since the element organizing section took me a lot of time everyday, I decided to write a simple organizer [**CLI application**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application), while preventing [**object-oriented programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) as much as possible ( Since I think that would add too much complexity for a simple application like this ) using [**Python argparse**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

##### I would kindly accept feedback on:

- Design patterns.

**organo.py**

---

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
KhodeNima's task organizer script.    
"""


from sys import argv as cli_arguments
from os import system as cmd_input
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
import argparse
import sys


argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="Organo", usage="organize_tasks --elements [] --filename Path | organize_tasks [--help, -h, -?]", add_help=True)
command_line_arguments = cli_arguments[1:cli_arguments.index(cli_arguments[-1])+1]
command_line_argument_amount = len(command_line_arguments)


color_red = "\33[31m"
color_default = "\33[0m"


def handle_help_argument_action() -> None:
    if command_line_argument_amount == 2 and "-help" in command_line_arguments:
        argument_parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()

    if command_line_argument_amount == 2 and "-?" in command_line_arguments:
        argument_parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()


def setup_help_arguments() -> None:
    argument_parser.add_argument("-?", help="Same as --help.", action="help")


def setup_element_arguments() -> None:
    argument_parser.add_argument("--elements", help="The elements to organize.", required=True, nargs="+", action="append")


def handle_filename_argument_action() -> str:
    filename_signature = "--filename"
    filename = ''.join([argument for argument in command_line_arguments if command_line_arguments[command_line_arguments.index(filename_signature) + 1] == argument])

    return filename
    

def setup_filename_argument() -> None:
    argument_parser.add_argument("--filename", help="The filename or path you want to write to ( relative to current ).", action="store", required=True)


def main() -> None:
    cmd_input("clear")
    
    file_name = handle_filename_argument_action()

    try:
        with open(f"{Path.cwd()}/{file_name}", "w"):
            pass

    except PermissionError:
        print(f"{color_red} Invalid permission for writing to file, run the command as root.")
        sys.exit()

    header_title = str(input("Please enter your desired header title: "))
    todo_text = f"---- {header_title} ----\n\n\n"

    

    elements = []
    for element in command_line_arguments:
        if element.startswith("--") or element.startswith("-") or element == "--elements":
            continue

        
        if command_line_arguments.index(element) < command_line_arguments.index("--elements"):
            continue

        
        elements.append(element)


    for task_id, task_title in enumerate(elements):
        task_id += 1
            
        organized_task = f"    {task_id}. {task_title}. \n\n"
        todo_text += organized_task
        

        if task_title == cli_arguments[-1]:
            todo_text += "\n ---- END ----"


    saved_file_path = f"{Path.cwd()}/{file_name}"
    with open(saved_file_path, "w") as todo_file:
        todo_file.write(todo_text)


    cmd_input(f"touch {Path.cwd()}/{file_name}")
    cmd_input(f"chmod 700 {Path.cwd()}/{file_name}")


    color_syntax = "\33[32m"
    cmd_input("clear")
                        
    print(f"{color_syntax}DONE.\33[0m")
    sleep(2)


    cmd_input("clear")


    should_open_file = input("Do you want to open the file? ( Y OR N )?: ")
    if should_open_file.lower() == "yes" or should_open_file.lower() == "y":
        webbrowser.open(saved_file_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_help_arguments()
    setup_element_arguments()
    setup_filename_argument()

    argument_parser.parse_args()
    handle_help_argument_action()
    main()

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonus points for that optional module docstring.
(Though I suspect possibly `pylint` "made" you do it.
I recommend preferring `ruff`, which doesn't get in your way,
over `pylint`, which by default is much too picky and counter-productive.)

## sort the imports

Your imports are weirdly organized, and not
[pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) compliant.
Don't give them a moment's thought.
Just run [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort)
and be done with it, move on to more interesting things.

## globals

You define a bunch of global symbols.

```
argument_parser = ...
command_line_arguments = ...
command_line_argument_amount = ...
color_red = ...
color_default = ...
```

Maybe this is good?
(Well, not that middle one, calling `len()` is too trivial to warrant defining it.)
Maybe you really need these, and didn't want to bury them within a `class`?
Ok, fair enough.

But at least mark them `_private`, e.g. `_command_line_arguments`.
As written, you are inviting folks to `import` them into other modules,
which does not appear to be your intent.
We make an effort to keep the namespace somewhat clean,
and scope things down within a smaller scope where feasible.
That way there's less
[coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)),
fewer things for the Gentle Reader to juggle in their head.

I will note in passing that pypi offers more than one
library that will help with ANSI escape sequences,
if you're willing to take an external dependency.

## prefer Path

```
def handle_filename_argument_action() -> str:
```

Thank you for the type annotation.

Prefer `Path` over `str` here.
It is more specific, so it more clearly communicates Author's Intent.
And there are lots of nice convenience methods hanging off of each Path object.

```
filename = ...
```

Yeah, you wrote some code there.

It extends way, waayyy beyond an 80-char horizontal scroll limit.

I didn't read it.

If you want others to read what you wrote, write it legibly.
You may find [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) helpful.
As written, Author is essentially telling folks "don't read this!".

"Handle" is a rather vague verb.
If this function is a getter, then prefer `get_` in its name.

## coupling

```
def setup_help_arguments() -> None:
    ...
def setup_element_arguments() -> None:
    ...
def setup_filename_argument() -> None:
```

These functions don't take any formal parameters.
Yet we *are* passing `argument_parser` to them,
implicitly, via the module namespace.

Don't do that.
Prefer to explicitly name the arg parser in the signature,
so the reader will quickly understand that we are
evaluating the function for side effects on *that* object.

Consider consolidating these rather small functions into a single function.

Re-evaluate your decision to not define a `class`.
When a bunch of functions accept similar argument,
via signature or via the module namespace,
that's the classic code smell that your functions
are asking to be grouped together in a class,
so they can share `self.arg_parser`.

## DRY

Please [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up
`handle_help_argument_action`.
For example you might choose to iterate in this way:

```
    for option in ['-?', '-help']:
        if ...
```

## long function

I count 64 lines in `main()`.
That's starting to get too long --
we need to vertically scroll in order to visually take it all in.

Consider breaking out one or more sections as
(individually testable!) helper functions.
Often `for` loops will be likely candidates.

Calling it `main` is not a terrible name.
But it is a bit vague,
and you neglected to offer a """docstring"""
explaining what it does, its
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

## unusual alias

```
from os import system as cmd_input
```

I recommend you just invoke the function as `os.system(...)`.
Giving it an unfamiliar name isn't helping others to understand what your code does.
The [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)
documentation is telling you that, instead of *this* ancient call,
you should prefer the newer
[subprocess.check_call()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call),
which does a better job of conveniently accomplishing what you wish here.

And, oh look! You turned the usual `sys.argv` into `cli_arguments`.
Less mysterious when someone reads it, but still, unnecessary.

Also, you defined ANSI escape codes for the color red,
but not for clear screen?!?
You'd rather the expense of forking off a /usr/bin/clear child?
Ok, I mean it works.
You might want to consider
[alternatives](https://pypi.org/search/?q=ansi+escape+codes).

## redundant type conversion

```
    ... = str(input( ... ))
```

We always get a `str` back from `input()`,
so there's no need to stringify an existing string here.

Notice that if user hits CTRL/C here we leave behind a turd file,
leftover from the write permission check.
So consider deleting that file prior to soliciting input.

## nested loops

```
    for element in command_line_arguments:
        ...
        if command_line_arguments.index(element) < command_line_arguments.index("--elements"):
```

That's a little weird.
Typical idiom would be to set a `bool` flag when we
encounter `"--elements"`, and then just test the flag.
(And for the number on the left that we're comparing,
a `for` loop using `enumerate` would give you that index directly.)

As written, cost of scanning N arguments is O(N²) quadratic.
We loop over N args, and for each arg we make linear scan of N args

Idioms like `find . | xargs cmd...` make "lots of args"
a more common occurrence than you might at first think.

## post-loop logic belongs after the loop

```
        if task_title == cli_arguments[-1]:
            todo_text += "\n ---- END ----"
```

That's just odd.

Elide the `if`, and exdent the assignment
so it executes unconditionally.

If you're concerned about the "no elements" case,
say so explicitly with an `if elements:` guard for
the whole thing.

## Path.resolve()

```
    saved_file_path = f"{Path.cwd()}/{file_name}"
```

Ok, I let it go the first time, but we keep seeing this idiom.

The type of `file_name` should be `Path`.

And then we should be assigning `... = file_name.resolve()`.
Or rather, up above we should have ensured that `file_name`
is *already* fully resolved.

This is robust to things like a user entering a `../dir/file` prefix,
or entering a fully qualified pathname, common when pasting it in.

## useless forks

```
    cmd_input(f"touch {Path.cwd()}/{file_name}")
    cmd_input(f"chmod 700 {Path.cwd()}/{file_name}")
```

I can't imagine what helpful effect that first one has,
given that our previous action was to write to that same file.
Elide it.

The `chmod` suffers from a
[TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)
race bug.
We *could* accomplish this more quickly with
[file_name.chmod(mode)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.chmod),
but that would still suffer from the race condition.
If you want to prohibit access for group+other,
you need to do that in the `open`, which accepts
an optional `..., mode=` parameter.

And then doing a chmod afterwards would be a
harmless belt-and-suspenders operation,
just in case the file already existed with wrong permission.

The permissions check should similarly be careful with the `mode` parameter.

## YORN

```
    if should_open_file.lower() == "yes" or should_open_file.lower() == "y":
```

You can DRY that up a little:

```
    if should_open_file.lower() in ["y", "yes"]:
```